# Three-ways Kruskal-Wallis test

Tags: r, kruskal-wallis-test

I need to make a Kruskal Wallis a three ways. The my dataset is composed by x (Presence) and three variable. I want to see the statistical difference of my x versus all the factors. I try to apply the Kruskal-Wallis test and I obtain this:

```
a <- IPU_L2$Phylum
b <- IPU_L2$Time
c <- IPU_L2$Treatment
d <- IPU_L2$Presence

dati <- list(g1=a, g2=b, g3=c, g4=d)

kruskal.test(dati)

    Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  dati
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 612.9894, df = 3, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

In case after how do I proceed? In case I use the `kruskalmc`?

---

*From comments:*
The my Y is the Presence and I want to check if the variables Class, Time and Treatment significantly influence the Presence. My dataset is not normally distributed and so I need to apply the Kruskal-Wallis test.

The my dataset is:

```
> str(IPU_L2) 'data.frame': 344 obs. of 9 variables: 
 $ Phylum : Factor w/ 43 levels "Acidobacteria", .. : 1641125371013264024 ... 
 $ Time : Factor w/ 2 levels "T0", "T56" : 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ... 
 $ Treatment : Factor w/4 levels "Control", "IPUx1", .. : 1111111111 ... 
 $ Presence : int 0 1 1 1 1 27 2 4 18 4 ... 
 $ sqrt : num 01111 ... 
 $ sqrt3 : num 0 1 1 1 1 ... 
 $ sqrt4 : num 01111 ... 
 $ x2 : int 0 1 1 1 1 729 4 16 324 16 ... 
 $ x3 : int 0 1 1 1 1 19683 8 64 5832 64 ... 
>
```

I am asking if is possible to run a Kruskal-Wallis test as a three way factorial ANOVA (because I need to analyze three factors).

Comment: Can you say more about your situation, your data, & your goals here? Are you trying to do a 2x2x2 factorial ANOVA with a non-normal response variable? Are you asking about post-hoc tests to run after a significant KW to determine which groups differ?

Comment: You refer to `Presence` as your "x". Is that your response / output variable?

Comment: The my Y is the Presence and I want to check if the variable Class, Time and Treatment are significant influence the Presence. My dataset is not normal distruited and I need to apply the kruskal wallis.

Comment: The my dataset is: > str(IPU_L2)
'data.frame': 344 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ Phylum   : Factor w/ 43 levels "Acidobacteria",..: 16 4 11 25 37 10 13 26 40 24 ...
 $ Time     : Factor w/ 2 levels "T0","T56": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Treatment: Factor w/ 4 levels "Control","IPU_x1",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Presence : int  0 1 1 1 1 27 2 4 18 4 ...
 $ sqrt     : num  0 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ sqrt3    : num  0 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ sqrt4    : num  0 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ x2       : int  0 1 1 1 1 729 4 16 324 16 ...
 $ x3       : int  0 1 1 1 1 19683 8 64 5832 64 ...
>

Comment: I ask if is possible to make a Kruskal Wallis a three way (because I need to analysis three factors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Kruskal-Wallis test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Wallis_one-way_analysis_of_variance) can be shown to be a simplified version of [ordinal logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_logit).  Although the KW test cannot handle a factorial design, OLR can.

If you are hoping to run your analysis in R, the excellent UCLA statistics help site has a tutorial on OLR [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/ologit.htm).